# Get-childitem sorted and then delete upon promt input

Tags: powershell

i try to sort a list and give it over as variable to then do something with the list. when i run the code without $files (the variable) then it list perfect. when i set the $files in front the output is nothing. what am i doing wrong ? i am very new to powershell and tried since hours to find the right combination, but i seem to not see thru.

this code below sorts exactly as wanted, but then delete is not working because $files is nowhere defined i think

```
 do {

Get-childitem -Path E:\TestEnv\deleted_images\ -recurse -include @("Image*") | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime
Group-Object Name -AsHashTable


    $files.Values
    $userinput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter Folder name to be deleted'

    if ($files.ContainsKey($userinput)) {
        $files[$userinput] | Remove-item
        Write-Host 'Folder was deleted'
    }
}
until([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userinput))
```

[image: result of code 1]

i tried this code, but does not even do get-childitem list

```
 do {

$files = Get-childitem -Path E:\TestEnv\deleted_images\ -recurse -include @("Image*") | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime
Group-Object Name -AsHashTable


    $files.Values
    $userinput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter Folder name to be deleted'

    if ($files.ContainsKey($userinput)) {
        $files[$userinput] | Remove-item
        Write-Host 'Folder was deleted'
    }
}
until([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userinput))
```

[image: result of code 2]

Comment: The first code never defines `$files` and in both codes you forgot the pipe `|` to Group-Object..

Comment: Instead of typing, check out uisng `Out-GridView` with the `-PassThru` parameter as an easy multi-select control...

Comment: @Theo thank you for the hint with the pipe. i added the pipe to the second code, now i get the listing, so first step is achieved. but now it does not sort based on the LastAccessTime, which it does when i remove the $files part. as soon as i add $files, the sorting does not work anymore

Comment: @Theo btw the script functionality is awesome, so thanks again. but as i am new to powershell i would really like to learn something from all this, even if it is little tiny step of the long path. got to start somewhere :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Read-Host` (where a user can type in just about anything..), I would use `Out-GridView` as [Keith Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953342/get-childitem-sorted-and-then-delete-upon-promt-input?noredirect=1#comment133968511_75953342) already suggested.

This will provide a graphical list of directories to the user making it much easier to select one or more directories to delete.

```
$path = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images'
# enter an endless loop. We'll break out if the user clicks the Cancel button
# or when there are no directories found that match the name in the Filter
while ($true) {
    # if you only want to match the name on a single wildcard string, use Filter, not Include
    $dirs = Get-childitem -Path $path -Filter 'Image*' -Recurse -Directory | Sort-Object LastAccessTime
    # only proceed if there are directories found by that name
    if (@($dirs).Count) {
        $selection = $dirs | Out-GridView -Title 'Please select the folder(s) to delete' -PassThru
        # if the user cancelled, exit the while loop
        if (!$selection) { break }

        # the user could have selected more than one directory, so use a loop
        $selection | ForEach-Object { 
            $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse
            Write-Host "Folder $($_.FullName) has been deleted"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No directories found that match the filter.."
        break  # no directory by that name found, so exit the while loop
    }
}

Write-Host "All done" -ForegroundColor Green
```

---

As per your comment you cannot use the graphical Out-GridView, here's the idea using a console menu.

```powershell
function Do-Menu {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$Path   = $PWD,  # default to current working directory
        [string]$Filter = 'Image*',
        [string]$Title  = 'Please select the folder(s) to delete'
    )
    cls

    # if you only want to match the name on a single wildcard string, use Filter, not Include
    $dirs = @(Get-childitem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse -Directory) | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
    # only proceed if there are directories found by that name
    if (!$dirs.Count) {
        Write-Host "No directories found that match filter '$Filter'.."
        return $false  # exit the function with a value of False
    }
    # create the menu
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Title)) {
        $dashLine = '-' * ($Title -split '\r?\n' | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
        Write-Host "$Title`r`n$dashLine`r`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    $index  = 1
    $dirs | ForEach-Object {
        # write out the menu items
        $align = $dirs.Count.ToString().Length
        # {0,$align} aligns the index number to the right
        # for more DateTime formats see
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
        Write-Host ("{0,$align}. {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  {2}" -f $index++, $_.LastWriteTime, $_.FullName)  
    }
    # now ask for user input
    $message = "`r`nType the index number of the directory you wish to delete.`r`n"
    if ($dirs.Count -gt 1) { $message += "To select multiple items, separate the numbers with commas.`r`n" }
    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $selection = Read-Host
    # make sure the input is all numeric and contains no '0' values
    # or values higher than the number of directories
    $selection = [int[]]($selection -replace '[^\d,]' -split ',' | 
                         Where-Object { $_ -match '\d+' -and ([int]$_ -gt 0 -and [int]$_ -le $dirs.Count)})

    if (!$selection.Count) { return $false }  # exit on empty input

    # loop over the selected indices and delete the matching folders
    $selection | ForEach-Object {
        $folder = $dirs[$_ - 1]
        # make sure you are not trying to remove a folder of which the parent
        # folder has just been removed
        if (Test-Path -Path $folder.FullName -PathType Container) {
            $folder | Remove-Item -Recurse
            Write-Host "Folder $($folder.FullName) has been deleted"
        }
    }
    # return True to have the menu rebuilt after a short pause
    Start-Sleep 4
    $true
}

# main code
$path = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images'

while ($true) {
    $result = Do-Menu -Path $path
    # if the user cancelled, or if there were no folders matching the filter, exit the while loop
    if (!$result) { break }
}
cls
Write-Host "`r`nAll done!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: ok that one is great and does everything i wanted and even easier with the output-gridview for the user. thank you very much for it. i will try to unterstand it in detail step by step

Comment: thank you again for that script i really appreciate your help. now i struggled over a new issue :) . i forgot to mention that i want the script to be able to run from a WinRM session. i tried to do it, but got a error telling me that out-gridview can not be used on a remote session, but promt input is. so will have to change it back to promt input. i will try it by myself if i can figure it and if not you could maybe give me a hint in the right direction. thank you and best regards, sanjacob

Comment: @sanjacob ok, I see. Then maybe a console menu could be helpful to make things easier for the user. How many folders should it show maximum you'd say? If the menu gets too long then that perhaps is not a good idea.. I'm on mobile now, but maybe I can give you an idea tomorrow

Comment: @Theoi think a maximum list of 25 folders. the image folders are snapshots of a hyperv test server on which we test software packages. after the package was tested we do a new snapshot if the package works as intendet to keep the status just in case. after max. 10 snapshots we start to delete the older snapshots, so 20 saved old versions should be enough to go back just in case we have too. no stress, enjoy easter and your free time :)) . whenever it's fine for you. thank you, i appreciate your help very much

Comment: @sanjacob Thanks, I have added new code to give you an idea of how you could do this with a menu in the console window. Hope you like it ;)

Comment: thank you again. see answer below please. i think that would help me more :))

Comment: btw i tested the script and it's awesome but is it possible to let the list (output) look like in the first picture of this thread upstairs. we need to see the lastwritetime  and the name, otherwise the user can not know which the oldest snapshots are :)) . thank you for your help

Comment: @sanjacob Ok, I have simplified the second code and also added the LastWriteTime to the menu

Comment: thank you very much again for your help. after the edit it does exactly what i tried to achieve, and it also works thru a the powershell winrm remote session. before we delete the snapshots we move them to the delete folder. thanks to your helping notes i could even change the script to use it as move-items script too and it works like a charm. just had to add a $targetdir, change from remove-item to move-item and add the destination parameter with the variable (see answer below for code)

Comment: i really learned a lot from you. still have to check out your script step by step which is a high learning curve though, but it will definitely be worth the time. so thank you again for everything :)) .

Answer (score 1):

here is the modified code which i use to first move the image folders to the delete folder.

```
 function Do-Menu {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$Path   = $PWD,  # default to current working directory
    [string]$Filter = 'Image*',
    [string]$Title  = 'Please select the folder(s) to move'
)
cls

# if you only want to match the name on a single wildcard string, use Filter, not Include
$dirs = @(Get-childitem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse -Directory) | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
# only proceed if there are directories found by that name
if (!$dirs.Count) {
    Write-Host "No directories found that match filter '$Filter'.."
    return $false  # exit the function with a value of False
}
# create the menu
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Title)) {
    $dashLine = '-' * ($Title -split '\r?\n' | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
    Write-Host "$Title`r`n$dashLine`r`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

$index  = 1
$dirs | ForEach-Object {
    # write out the menu items
    $align = $dirs.Count.ToString().Length
    # {0,$align} aligns the index number to the right
    # for more DateTime formats see
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
    Write-Host ("{0,$align}. {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  {2}" -f $index++, $_.LastWriteTime, $_.FullName)  
}
# now ask for user input
$message = "`r`nType the index number of the directory you wish to delete.`r`n"
if ($dirs.Count -gt 1) { $message += "To select multiple items, separate the numbers with commas.`r`n" }
Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Yellow

$selection = Read-Host
# make sure the input is all numeric and contains no '0' values
# or values higher than the number of directories
$selection = [int[]]($selection -replace '[^\d,]' -split ',' | 
                     Where-Object { $_ -match '\d+' -and ([int]$_ -gt 0 -and [int]$_ -le $dirs.Count)})

   

 if (!$selection.Count) { return $false }  # exit on empty input

    # loop over the selected indices and delete the matching folders
    $selection | ForEach-Object {
        $folder = $dirs[$_ - 1]
        # make sure you are not trying to remove a folder of which the parent
        # folder has just been removed
        if (Test-Path -Path $folder.FullName -PathType Container) {
            $folder | Move-Item -Destination $targetdir
            Write-Host "Folder $($folder.FullName) has been moved"
        }
    }
    # return True to have the menu rebuilt after a short pause
    Start-Sleep 4
    $true
}

# main code
$path = 'E:\TestEnv\Repository\images'
$targetdir = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images' 

while ($true) {
    $result = Do-Menu -Path $path
    # if the user cancelled, or if there were no folders matching the filter, exit the while loop
    if (!$result) { break }
}
cls
Write-Host "`r`nAll done!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: There is a case, where the contents of the folder change during the running of this script, where deleting by index from a sorted list can delete the wrong item.  I would suggest prompting with the selected folder name in order to provide a check.  "$folder.fullname will be deleted. Continue? (y,N)"

Comment: Also, passing $selection through a pipe and using it once as $_ is needlessly complicated.  Why not just use `$folder = $dirs[ $selection - 1 ]`?  Also, the pattern of pipelining is typically used on the commandline.  In scripts, we have the luxury of spelling things out.  This makes the code easier to follow. This is a 'best practice' issue, not one of syntax.

Comment: @Jeter-work i am very new to powershell and still working on figuring out step by step how the script i received is working. the point with the "prompting with the selected folder name" is a good idea. could you explain (show) me excatly where that code part should be added/inserted ? thank you very much